# Is it possible to copy an item from one list and put into another multiple times, and then modify each item individually?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am working on a card game project that is a similar concept to Hearthstone's Battlegrounds mode (for practice, and fun). I am trying to put two or more of the same card in the players hand and then modify its values individually. Currently, when one card is supposed to be modified, it changes both.

First, I bring in the monsters json and deepcopy it into a list so I can 1) modify the entries and 2) keep a reference for the original values:

```
gameDeck = []
with open('monsters.json', 'r') as f:
    monsters = json.load(f)
gameDeck = copy.deepcopy(monsters)
```

An example of a monster entry (it is a dictionary within a list):

```
[
  { "name": "Jerry",
    "hp": 1,
    "str": 1,
    "type": "human",
    "amount": 10,
    "ability": "",
    "ability-property":"",
    "ability-property-amount":""
  },
```

I then add the card to the users hand (by force, for testing):

```
def forceAssignUser(user, gameDeck):
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)
```

.addCard looks like:

```
class Player:
    #...

    # adds a card to the players hand, removes the card from the deck
    def addCard(self, card, gameDeck):
        self.hand.append(card)
        # gameDeck.remove(card)
        card['amount'] -= 1
```

Now of course, when running and during 'combat' phase, when one card takes damage, so does it's duplicate. I tried this but ended up the same result:

```
def forceAssignUser(user, gameDeck):
    card = copy.deepcopy(gameDeck[0])
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)
```

Here is what a part of the 'combat' phase looks like, where most of the changes happen (not pretty, I know):

```
    while userAlive is not False and opponentAlive is not False:
        if whoseTurn == "u":
            if userMonAtk >= len(user.hand):
                #what monster will attack
                userMonAtk = 0
            while checkCardHealth(user, userMonAtk) <= 0:
                #use next monster if current is dead
                userMonAtk += 1
            #choose a random target
            randOpponentMon = random.randint(0, len(user.hand) - 1)
            while opponent.hand[randOpponentMon]['hp'] <= 0:
                #reroll if chosen enemy dead
                randOpponentMon = random.randint(0, len(user.hand) - 1)
            usMonster = user.hand[userMonAtk] #store the card info
            opMonster = opponent.hand[randOpponentMon]
            opMonster['hp'] -= usMonster['str'] #when attacking or being attacked, take damage
            usMonster['hp'] -= opMonster['str']
            printBoard(user, opponent)
            print("Your {0} attacks opponent's {1}!".format(usMonster['name'], opMonster['name']))
            opponentAlive = checkDeckHealth(opponent)
            userAlive = checkDeckHealth(user)
            input("Press anything to continue.")
            whoseTurn = "o"
            userMonAtk += 1
```

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do? I am not amazing at coding, so a lot of my code revolves around logic, methods, and a class.

Comment: how does a card look like? is it a dictionary? and where is it stored?

Comment: @Matiiss I included an example of what a card looks like (Jerry). It is a dictionary within a list, stored in a json file that I import as another list (gameDeck) and reference throughout the code.

Comment: I suggest storing all cards in a dictionary and assigning different keys to them (so basically a dictionary inside a dictionary) and then reference them like that: `all_cards['card1']['hp'] -= 1` if You understand what I am saying. so basically if You had the same card they still would have different keys for example `card1` and `card2` (but still the same name) and then You would access them like mentioned before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple. When you tried to add `deepcopy`, you still added an alias twice:

```
def forceAssignUser(user, gameDeck):
    card = copy.deepcopy(gameDeck[0])
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)   # Same card as before
```

If you want to add a card with the same values, but not an *alias* to the *same* `card`, copy twice:

```
def forceAssignUser(user, gameDeck):
    card = gameDeck[0]
    user.addCard(copy.deepcopy(card), gameDeck)   # Different from gameDeck[0]
    user.addCard(copy.deepcopy(card), gameDeck)   # Different from gameDeck[0] and previous line's copy
```

Your "fixed" code did mean `gameDeck[0]` was different from the copy you inserted twice, rather than having *three* aliases, but it was still inserting the exact same card twice.

Note that it looks like your intent was to have the card *removed* from the `gameDeck`, so you could avoid one level of copying by doing that:

```
def forceAssignUser(user, gameDeck):
    card = gameDeck.pop(0)  # Removes card from gameDeck (no alias; it's now owned solely by you)
    user.addCard(card, gameDeck)   # Insert original card to user's hand (no need to copy)
    user.addCard(copy.deepcopy(card), gameDeck)   # Insert a second copy of the card (must copy to avoid aliasing)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! However, I actually don't want to entirely remove the card from the gameDeck, hence why I am testing duplicate cards. I actually want to just reduce the amount of cards available in the pool (each card has a certain amount, which is 10 currently). I took your card = copy.deepcopy(card) suggestion and added it into the addCard method and it allows me to modify the amount of cards in the deck while still having two separate duplicate cards. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a couple of objects (Python's `object` built-in is useful stand-in since it repr includes its address):

```
>>> o1,o2=object(), object()
>>> o1
<object object at 0x10817e430>
>>> o2
<object object at 0x10817e450>
```

Now make a list of these objects:

```
>>> li=[o1,o2]
>>> li
[<object object at 0x10817e430>, <object object at 0x10817e450>]
```

A typical copy will use a slice to do a shallow copy:

```
>>> li_copy=li[:]
>>> li_copy
[<object object at 0x10817e430>, <object object at 0x10817e450>]
```

That means that `li` and `li_copy` are two different lists; you can modify one without modifying the other:

```
>>> li_copy[0]='not an object() anymore'
>>> li
[<object object at 0x10817e430>, <object object at 0x10817e450>]
>>> li_copy
['not an object() anymore', <object object at 0x10817e450>]
```

Even though they are two separate lists, they do contain the same objects; if you MODIFY `<object object at 0x10817e430>` it will change in `li` too.

But if you use `deepcopy` you get two separate lists with two independent objects:

```
>>> import copy
>>> li_3=copy.deepcopy(li)
>>> li_3
[<object object at 0x10817e4b0>, <object object at 0x10817e4c0>]
# note that the addresses have changed - these are new objects that could
# be modified without changing the object in the other list.
```

Not all object support deepcopying; sometimes the deepcopy function will simple do the same thing as doing a slice copy.

Deepcopy needs to be defined by defining the `__deepcopy__()` it must support the functionality of creating a new object that has the default values of the first instance but is a new instance. It the case of `object()` which is just a dumb object, it just calls `object()` again.

So the way to do this in your case is define a `Card` object and define a `__deepcopy__` method that creates a new card with the values of the copy source.